# Size of Xcode app seems too big at over 12GB? Is this correct?

Tags: macos, applications, xcode, mac-appstore

Xcode in App Store listed at 4.51GB. The same version of Xcode on my iMac is over 12GB. I understand the value may be different on the App Store but this seems like a huge difference. Is this 12 GB size accurate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App Store sizes are reported as the compressed download, which for Xcode is around 5 GB. Once downloaded, uncompressed and installed, over 10 GB is the size observed in Finder.